# Powershell Searching within a text file and exporting horizontally to CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a big file which content somme blocks of text data like this.

```
[SERVER1]
LIBELLE=DATA, SOMME DATA
VARIABLES=A,B,C,D,E
PHYSICAL NAME=E:\SOMME\PATH\FILE.INI
ARTICLE SIZE=50
MACHINE=SOME SERVER 
PARAMETER =
OPTION = 

[SERVER2]
LIBELLE=DATA2, SOMME DATA2
VARIABLES=A,B,C,D,E
PHYSICAL NAME=Z:\SOMME\PATH\FILE2.INI
ARTICLE SIZE=150
MACHINE=SOME SERVER XY
PARAMETER =
OPTION 1 = VOID 
OPTION 2 = 
OPTION 3 = 
OPTION 4 = 
OPTION 5 =
```

What i would like to do is retrieving every block [SERVERX]  and put it into a CSV file in this format (horizontally)

```
ColumnA__    |  ColumnB (LIBELLE)___  |  ColumnC (VARIABLES) | ColumnD ect...

[SERVER1]  |  DATA1, SOMME DATA1 |  A,B,C,D,E___________           | Ect...

[SERVER2]  |  DATA2, SOMME DATA2 |  A,B,C,D,E___________           | Ect...
```

I've tried this, the output work as i want but it need to be automated and exported to scv, which doesn't work for me.

```
$mydata = Get-Content my_file.txt
write-Host $mydata[0] $mydata[1] $mydata[2] $mydata[3] $mydata[4] $mydata[5] | Export-Csv -Path $rep\results.csv -Force -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Tried also somthing with select-string but i dont know if this is the right way to do my job..

```
select-String -path $my_file -Pattern '\[*\]', 'IDENTIFIANTS=','LIBELLE=','VARIABLES=' | Select-Object -Property LineNumber, Line | Export-Csv -Path $rep\results.csv -Force -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: `Export-CSV` requires more complex objects beyond lines to functions. You need to make custom object with this data. Also to account that the data sets are not the same. Options is different in both. Are you keeping all the data for the expot?  Are you set one those column names? Can LIBELLE just be LIBELLE? Programmatically this makes more sense.

Comment: Your source data looks mostly, but not completely, to have the same columns for each [OBJECT]. Do you need new columns created dynamically if you encounter a key-value pair with a key that hasn't been seen before?

Comment: @Matt : Are you keeping all the data for the expot? --> Yes
Are you set one those column names? Can LIBELLE just be LIBELLE? --> Yes the columns are the same, i may have more new columns depending on data block but i'm still keeping the existing ones.

Comment: @Charlie Joynt : Yes

Answer (score 1):

So, I would read the whole file in as a multi-line string using the -Raw switch for `Get-Content`. Then split the file up based on the `[` character to denote records. The get the properties from the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet (have to prepend "SERVER=" to each record), and make an object from it. Then we find out what all properties any given record can have, make sure to add them all to the first record if it doesn't have it (this is done because when you export to CSV it bases the columns off of the first entries' property list). Then you can export a CSV.

```
$Data = (Get-Content my_file.txt -Raw) -split "(\[[^[]+)" | ?{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}
$Records = $Data -replace '\\','\\'|%{$Record="SERVER="+$_.trim()|ConvertFrom-StringData;New-Object PSObject -Prop $Record}
$Props = $Records|%{$_.psobject.properties.name}|select -Unique
$Props | Where{$_ -notin $Records[0].PSObject.Properties.Name}|%{Add-Member -InputObject $Records[0] -NotepropertyName $_ -NotepropertyValue $Null}
$Records|Export-CSV .\my_file.csv -notype
```

**Edit:** For those of you out there running PowerShell 2.0 (3 versions out of date at this point in time), you can't use the `-Raw` parameter. Here's the alternative:

```
$Data = (Get-Content my_file.txt) -Join "`r`n" -split "(\[[^[]+)" | ?{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}
```

**Alternative:** Thanks @Matt for the suggestion, it is always good to have a different point of view on these things. As Matt suggested, you can use `Out-String` to combine the array of strings that `Get-Content` generates, and end up with a single multi-line string. Here's the usage!

```
$Data = (GC my_file.txt | Out-String) -split "(\[[^[]+)" | ?{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}
```

Comment: This is what I was coming back to answer with once the OP answered my questions. This is the right approach for structured data.

Comment: I've just tried your proposition, but it doesn't work, the "-Raw" parameter is not reconized because i'm on Windows 7 pro with Powershell version 2.0.
Sorry i'm pretty new to PS.

Comment: I always found `| Out-String` to be easier to handle for the 2.0ers

Comment: Thanks guys, but i'm still having a problem, "-notin" seems to be unsuported also..
After a little search i may have to use "-notcontains" but i dont know how to adapt it in your script.

Comment: Ah, you are using an old version of PowerShell... right. So `-notcontains` is like a backwards `-notin`... `If($x -notin $y)` is the same as `If($y -notcontains $x)`

Comment: Please could you help with a compatible V2 Powershell script ? 
I couldn't adapt your propositions.